# How to start Cassandra on a server individually for each user

Tags: database, cassandra

Sorry, I'm a newbie to databases and am using Cassandra mainly to collect and store statistics from my simulations that I'm running.
Basically I have a logger which stores the collected statistics into a Cassandra database.

At this moment, I have one version of Cassandra running on my server. I started it as a service. I have couple of users that are running simulations on the server at the same time. With one instance of Cassandra as a service running on the server, all logs are stored in the same database. However I was hopeful that each user once starts running simulations, also starts his/her own copy of Cassandra and once done, stop Cassandra.

Is that something that can be done with Cassandra? I understand I'm somewhat changing the use case for Cassandra, but wondering if that can be done.

BTW, the main reason for using Cassandra is that I can't have the same schema for all different logs and statistics that are generated. So sql-based databases were not options for me.

Answer (score 2):

The problem as you describe it is overkill for Cassandra - it's designed for building distributed database, running on multiple servers.  If you just need "local" key-value store you can look into RocksDB, or something like.

If you still need to stick to Cassandra, you have several options:

- Have Cassandra running all the time, but give every user separate keyspace (if you need several tables inside it), or table (if data is in the single table).  These keyspaces/tables could be removed after emulation finishes;
- Run Cassandra in the Docker container - in this case, every user gets the dedicated instance, but machine will need more resources if you run multiple simulations at the same time.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the insight. Typically how heavy is Cassandra? When talking about resources, I assume you mainly mean storage resources? Is that the case? Is Cassandra both processing heavy and storage heavy? I hope I don't have to go away from Cassandra as I've already moved my whole team towards using Cassandra.

Comment: I meant that it consumes memory, CPU, etc. With low memory you can easy get OOM. Cassandra shines in distributed use case, but overkill for single machine